# SAP Query: upper case and replace possible?

Tags: abap, opensql

Our application has a GUI for selecting devices by their MAC address. At this time I have to enter the MAC address in captial letters and with colons.

However, I often have the MAC address in Windows format, which is lower case and with hyphens instead of colons.

The developers keep telling me that it's not possible to apply an uppercase transformation and replace the hyphens by colons. In this project I'm working as QA and I'm neither familiar with SAP Query nor ABAP. But being a developer for C# and Java projects, I really can't believe this.

**Is there a way in SAP Query to transform user input from e.g. `aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff` to match the database content `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`?**

The datatype is C length 17. The program GUI at the time filling the query with the parameters is RSSYSTDB. The Program Dynpro at that time is AQZZ/xxx/yyy where xxx is our partner namespace and yyy corresponds to the transaction. The program GUI and Program DynPro when the result is displayed is SAPLAQRUNT.

Comment: Do you mean "SAP Query" as in "transaction `SQ*"` or as a generic term?

Comment: What are the program names displayed in System > Status? ("Programm Dynpro" and "Programm GUI" in German)?

Comment: @KeithHall 1. You could have linked to the official docs at https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abaptranslate.htm instead of some unofficial site that still presents obsolete syntax variants, but more importantly 2. that's not going to be of much help if we're talking about SAP Query, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data element is used exclusively to store MAC addresses (i. e. it's not some generic "device information data" field), the developers could implement a (very concise and easy to implement) [conversion routine](https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENCONVERSION_EXITS.htm). That would also help users entering the data. Other than that, I believe the options provided by SAP Query are more than limited...